# PHP For Loop repeating an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, calendar

I'm trying to create a calendar system that will show what jobs are booked in for certain days, I want it to be a horizontal calendar that has all of the days of the months as a table row and days of the week as the next row.  I've got the first row sorted but I need to have the second row repeat the array of the days of the week until the month ends.

```
      //Establish How many days are in the current Month
  $currentMonthDays = date("t");




  $daysOfWeek = array('M','T','W','T','F','Sa','Su');

      echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="ffffff">
            <tr>';


                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $currentMonthDays; $i++)
                    {

                        echo '<td width="30" align="center">'.$i.'</td>';
                    }

      echo '</tr><tr>';


                    foreach($daysOfWeek as $day){
                    echo '<td width="30" align="center">'.$day.'</td>';
                    }


      echo '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 //Establish How many days are in the current Month
  $currentMonthDays = date("t");
  $daysOfWeek = array('M','T','W','T','F','Sa','Su');
      for ($i = 0; $i <= $currentMonthDays-1; $i++){
          $arrayWeekDays[] = $daysOfWeek[($i%7)];
      }
      echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="ffffff">
            <tr>';


                    for ($i = 1; $i <= $currentMonthDays; $i++)
                    {

                        echo '<td width="30" align="center">'.$i.'</td>';
                    }

      echo '</tr><tr>';


                    foreach($arrayWeekDays as $day){
                    echo '<td width="30" align="center">'.$day.'</td>';
                    }


      echo '</tr>';
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Super @waren0809 awesome, Good Job

Comment: Thanks @Muthusamy :)

Comment: Thanks that's great, I suspected I would have to use modulus at some point but was breaking my brain going around in circles.  Now I need to start on all the other little sticking points like establishing what day the month starts on, how many cells to offest that by etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    $currentMonthDays = date("t");

    $daysOfWeek = array('M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'Sa', 'Su');

    echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="ffffff">
        <tr>';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $currentMonthDays; $i++) {

        if ($i % 7 == 1) 
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        echo '<td width="30" align="center">' . $i . '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr><tr>';


    foreach ($daysOfWeek as $day) {
            echo '<td width="30" align="center">' . $day . '</td>';
    }


    echo '</tr>';
```

maybe helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this to use the `DateTime` class and formatting methods you used to get the number of days to also format the date for you.

```
$currentMonthDays = date('t');
$month = date('m');
$year = date( 'Y');

for ($i = 1; $i <= $currentMonthDays; $i++) {
    echo '<td width="30" align="center">'.$i.'</td>';
}
$day = new DateTime();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $currentMonthDays; $i++) {
    $day->setDate( $year, $month, $currentMonthDays);
    // this outputs first 3 letters of day, but you can truncate if you want..
    echo '<td width="30" align="center">'.$day->format('D').'</td>';
}
```

You could also avoid the need for 2 loops by merging the two `td`s and formatting the cell by either adding a `br` element between the day of the month and the day of the week, or using CSS formatting.